# Underline <h1> within a div

Tags: css, border

I'm trying to underline a `h1`-title, but for some reason it always takes the whole length of the parent div. The only way I was able to do so, was by adding the `position: absolute`-property in the css...

This is the design:
[image]

And this is what I get:
[image]

Point is to get the blue line only as wide as the `h1` and a gray border line under the parent div.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>Contacteer ons</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
h1 {
    border-bottom: 8px solid #57c4d0;
    position: absolute; /* As I've said, adding this allowed me to do so, but the result was far from ideal! */
}

.title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
}
```

I'm planning on using the HTML across my whole website (each `h1` will be different in length, adding a fixed width on each title isn't an option), so I'm looking for a robust solution. Anyone with advice?

Comment: `<h1>` is a block element, and will span the width of its parent. That's why your underline goes across the screen - the h1 is really that wide, even though the text in it isn't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change `h1` to `display: inline-block;`

See a live example at (added `margin-bottom` to `.title` for clarity):

http://jsfiddle.net/P4BGC/

Answer (score 1):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtTwj/). H1 is a a block element, so it grows to fill its parent. You can set `display: inline`, but I also suggest to put it in its own div (or any other element with `display: block`) so you ensure that no content goes along side.

```
<div><h1>Hello, world</h1></div>
Lorem ipsum
```

the css

```
​h1 {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  display: inline;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use CSS style `text-decoration`.

html:

```html
<div><h1>Hello, world</h1></div>
```

css:

```css
    h1 {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```